# Byzantine behaviour in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I wrote the following script to interactively and recursively remove orphan backup files, i.e. remove each `file.txt~` that does not have a corresponding `file.txt`.

```
#!/bin/sh -x

set -o errexit
unalias -a

backups=$(find . -name "*~")

orphans=""
while read -r file
do
    [ ! -e "${file%~}" ] && orphans=$(echo "$file\n$orphans");
done << EOF
$backups
EOF

if [ -z "$orphans" ]; then
    echo "No orphans."
else
    echo "orphans:\n$orphans"
    echo "$orphans" | xargs --interactive -d '\n' rm
fi
```

This script does very weird things in a random fashion.  Sometimes it behaves correctly, sometimes it ignores the -x options passed to sh, sometimes it executes commented code, sometimes the tests give just wrong results.

The problem seems to be related to the here script, since by redirecting the output of find to a temporary file all problems seem to disappear.  But why, where is the error?

---

**Solution** (thanks to [Dennis Williamson](https://superuser.com/questions/234914/byzantine-behaviour-in-shell-script/234929#234929)):  Escape the `~` character.  The unescaped `~` in the parameter expansion `${file%~}` was creating somehow all the unpredictable behavior.

---

A more readable and deterministic solution, with some fat cut out, could be (thanks to the suggestions of [Mikel](https://superuser.com/questions/234914/byzantine-behaviour-in-shell-script/234930#234930)):

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS='
'
for backup in $(find . -type f -name "*~"); do
    if [ ! -e "${backup%\~}" ]; then
        rm -i "$backup"
    fi
done
```

If you are a `while read` loop fan, things get less elegant because the interactive command `rm -i` can not be used (it will conflict with the `read` command).  Anyway, a solution could be:

```
#!/bin/sh
orphans=""
while read -r backup; do
    if [ ! -e "${backup%\~}" ]; then
        orphans=$(echo "$backup\n$orphans");
fi
done << EOF
$(find . -type f -name "*~")
EOF

if [ ! -z "$orphans" ]; then
    echo "$orphans" | xargs --interactive -d '\n' rm
fi
```

Or, a more complex way is also suggested by [Dennis Williamson](https://superuser.com/questions/234914/byzantine-behaviour-in-shell-script/234929#234929).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to escape the tilde in the brace expansion, otherwise it will get expanded to your home directory.

Why don't you pipe the `find` into your `while` loop instead of creating variables to hold them? Inside your loop, just do `rm -i "$file"`.

```
#!/bin/sh -x

set -o errexit
unalias -a

exec 3<&0    # open a duplicate of stdin
flag=false
find . -name "*~" | while IFS=$'\n' read -r file
do
    if [ ! -e "${file%\~}" ]
    then
        orphans="$file"$'\n'"$orphans"

        # use an alternate file descriptor so read and rm -i get along
        rm -i "$file" <&3
        flag=true
    fi
done
exec 3<&-    # close the file descriptor

if ! $flag
then
    echo "No orphans."
else
    echo "orphans:\n$orphans"
fi
```

If you want to use Bash, you need to move the `find` to the end of the loop so a subshell is not created.

```
#!/bin/bash

...

# use an alternate file descriptor so read and rm -i get along
while read -u 3 -r ...

    rm -i ...
    ...

done 3< <(find ...)

...
```

Comment: +1.  Tilde definitely needs escaping.  Also agree there would be simpler ways to write this.

Comment: Thanks!  The problem was in the escaping of `~`.  Now everything works in a comfortable deterministic way.  BTW, your script does not work with interactive rm, I suppose because the read command will conflict with it.

Comment: I am using bash 4.1.5(1)-release and the sub-shell is still created by the pipe.  So the redirection of the `find` output into the `while` command must be done.  You should also delete the leftover `$` in the `orphans` concatenation line.

Comment: @mrucci: That dollar sign is to create the newline: `$'\n'`

Comment: Yes, I'm guessing `rm -i` reads from stdin, which is supplied by the heredoc, rather than from `/dev/tty`.

Comment: mmm, I tested the script as is and the `$` gets inserted as a literal character inside the orphans variable.  Maybe you want to change `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash`.

Comment: Yes, both Dennis's example and my example use `$'\n'`.  If you are on Debian or Ubuntu, you have to change that to a literal newline (i.e. press Enter), because `/bin/sh` doesn't support that.

Comment: `$'\n'` comes from ksh93 AFAICT, and is also available in zsh and bash, but not dash. http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh-man.html#Quoting

Comment: @mrucci: Please see the edits in my answer (marked by comments). The use of alternate file descriptors will allow `rm -i` to be used within a `while read` loop.

Comment: @Dennis: wow, that's complicated, but it works!  I updated the  question with the solution to the original problem and with the various alternative versions of the script.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean "sometimes"?  Sometimes on the same box?  Or different behavior on different systems?

What do you mean "executes commented code"?  Your example doesn't have any comments.

Some thoughts:

- try `set -x` in place of `/bin/sh -x`
- <del>better to use `set -e` than `set -o errexit`</del>
- if you're using bash, then call `/bin/bash`, not `/bin/sh`, which could be something else
- echo is unnecessary, just use `=` with a literal newline
- if you do have to use `echo`, you should use `echo -e` or ensure `xpg_echo` is set
- your orphans line is putting them in reverse order, is that deliberate?
- your read loop will fail if file names contain spaces, you should set `IFS` first

A simpler version:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x
set -e

IFS=$'\n'
orphans=false
for backup in $(find . -type f -name "*~"); do
    original=${backup%\~}
    if [ ! -e "$original" ]; then
        orphans=true
        rm -i "$backup"
    fi  
done

if ! $orphans; then
    echo "No orphans."
fi
```

Or if you want it to work using `/bin/sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -x
set -e

IFS='
'
orphans=false
for backup in $(find . -type f -name "*~"); do
    original=${backup%\~}
    if [ ! -e "$original" ]; then
        orphans=true
        rm -i "$backup"
    fi  
done

if ! $orphans; then
    echo "No orphans."
fi
```

Comment: Why are your `set` commands better? It's more readable to use `$'\n' (or echo) than a literal newline. In some shells `echo` doesn't understand `-e` (they echo it literally) and do the escape processing by default. That's why it's often better to use `printf` since it is consistent.

Comment: He said he was using bash.  This allows me to say use `echo -e`.  Otherwise you really need `printf` for consistent behavior on all platforms, but that's an external command in bash, so `echo -e` is correct and faster in this case.

Comment: I said use `set -x` because he was using the `-x` option.  For consistency and because I think the `set -<flag>` form is more common than `set -o <optname>`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I could use find inside the for loop that easily.  Good point about the unnecessary echo, I was totally in an "echo frenzy" state.  The loop will not fail when files have spaces in them.  Your solution does not work with /bin/sh, but only with bash but I can't see why.

Comment: If you're not using bash, you have to replace `IFS=$'\n'` with `IFS='<ENTER>'`.

Comment: Where did you read that? I never saw it, and it does't work.

Comment: Don't type `<ENTER>`.  Press the Enter key.  :-)  I edited my example above to show you.

Comment: Ha! Got it.  Works perfectly.

Comment: `printf` is a builtin in Bash. It may not be in some versions of the Bourne `sh`. Some people set `IFS` to a newline in shells that don't support `$'\n'` like this: `IFS=$(printf '%b' '\n\b')` (the backspace is a guard character since a trailing (or solo) newline would get dropped).

Comment: Oops, you're right.  But wow, that way of setting IFS looks even worse than `IFS='<newline>'` to me. :-)